# TypeScript instanceof not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, casting, instanceof

I'm having issues using the instanceof operator and it doesn't seem to work. Here is a part of my code:

```
        const results = _.map(items, function(item: Goal|Note|Task, index: number) { 
            let result = {};
            if (item instanceof Goal) {
                result = { id: index, title: item.name };
            } else if (item instanceof Note) {
                result = { id: index, title: item.content.text };
            } else if (item instanceof Task) {
                result = { id: index, title: item.name };
            }

            console.log(item);
            console.log(item instanceof Goal);
            console.log(item instanceof Note);
            console.log(item instanceof Task);

            return result; 
        });
```

All of my logs say false, here is what the console looks like:

[image: No type matched]

None of them match, despite being explicit that only the 3 types would be possible. You could also see the object itself with a typename of Goal, so I don't get why it doesn't match with instanceof Goal.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you generating `items`? Are they created through constructors? If not, they won't be instances of a given class.

Comment: Did you copy the object perhaps? Through JSON.parse or Object.assign?

Comment: They are responses from an API/http call. Must by why their typeofs are always objects as opposed to specific types?

Comment: @AnimaSola Right. For `instanceof` to work, you need to actual make them from constructors. Otherwise they're just objects that happen to have the same shape as your desired objects.

Comment: Thanks @MikeC, opted to use hasOwnProperty instead.

Comment: @AnimaSola or just use typeguards. :)

Comment: I don't consider any of the solutions on StackOverflow to be a comprehensive solution to the problem.

So, I created an npm package angular-http-deserializer for this:
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-deserializer#usage

Answer (score 25):

`instanceof` will return true only if it matches the function or class from which it was constructed. The `item` here is a plain `Object`.

```
const a = { a: 1 } // plain object
console.log(a);

// {a:1}                 <-- the constructor type is empty
//   a: 1
//   __proto__: Object   <-- inherited from

a instanceof A         // false because it is a plain object
a instanceof Object    // true because all object are inherited from Object
```

If it is constructed using a constructor function or a class, then instanceof will work as expected:

```
function A(a) {
    this.a = a;
}

const a = new A(1);    // create new "instance of" A
console.log(a);

// A {a:1}               <-- the constructor type is `A`

a instanceof A         // true because it is constructed from A
a instanceof Object    // true
```

If `Goal` is an `Interface` it will only check the structure of the object not its type. If `Goal` is a constructor then it should return true for `instanceof` checks.

Try something like:

```
// interface Goal {...}
class Goal {...}        // you will have to change the way it works.

items = [
   new Goal()
];
```

### Update 2021:

Been playing with Typescript recently and came up with a better solution that works both in Typescript and JavaScript:

Try something like:

```
interface Goal {
    getCount(): number;
}

class Goal implements Goal {
    getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}

function getItemCount(item: Goal | Note | Task) {
    return item instanceof Goal ? item.getCount() : 'not a goal';
}

console.log(getItemCount(new Goal()));  // 3
console.log(getItemCount('goal'));      // 'not a goal';
```

Here the interface and the class have the same name, so they can be used both as a type and as a constructor.

Changing the interface `Goal` signature or class `Goal` signature would throw something like:

```
TS2394: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.
```

Comment: Sadly, I've got a case where typeof fails for objects that have been created with a constructor. Logging them will show the correct type, yet the check still fails.

Comment: @mcv `typeof` does not give you the type in JavaScript, typeof only works for primitive types, meaning you will get `Object` as the result for any type checks. You might want to try comparing `obj.constructor`. Here is, [constructor reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) and [typeof reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Comment: It explains how it works, sure. But it doesn't provide a solution?

Comment: @GopikrishnaS That was a typo on my part; I did mean `instanceof`, not `typeof`. The reason it failed in my case what that a different class of the same name existed in the project, and somehow that one got imported in that file instead of the one I meant. (I've since refactored the two different-but-similar data models into a single unambiguous one.)

Comment: @CularBytes the answer is: Use the constructor, or instanceof wont work.

Comment: @CularBytes the question was, or rather the statement was "instanceof not working" and I explained "how it actually works" and the solution in the second part "Try something like:"

Answer (score 5):

You can also use type guards to your advantage:

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/typeGuard.html

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

For instance, if you use a literal type guard to your class:

```
class Goal {
 type: 'goal'
...
}
```

then the check is as simple as :

```
if (item.type === 'goal') {
}
```

Or you could write your own type guards:

```
function isNote(arg: any): arg is Note {
    // because only your Note class has "content" property?
    return arg.content !== undefined;
}

if (isNote(item)) {
    result = { id: index, title: item.content.text };
}
```

Comment: You would still have to set the `type` when the object is loaded from the API. But it is a bit of a easier solution then the others provide.

Answer (score 3):

as @Gopikrishna pointed out, object parsed from `JSON.parse` or received from API will not match your custom `Class` because it is not created via `new` operator of desired class.

One workaround is to first cast object to the desired class and then check for a property against `undefined`.

```
class User{
displayName:string;
id:string;
}

const user = obj as User;
if (user.displayName!==undefined) {
    //do your thing here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to instantiate the object with a constructor. It happened to me the same because I was manually mocking the object for testing purposes. If you create the item like following example, it should work:

```
item: Goal = new Goal(*item values*)
```

Answer (score 0):

From MDN:

> The instanceof operator tests to see if the prototype property of a
> constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object. The
> return value is a boolean value.