# Typescript generics accepts Object type?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript2.0

(Maybe obvious, but I'm new to both Typescript and Generics)

In my scenario only objects B and C extend object A and I have the following  function:

```
doSomething<T extends A>(param: T) {
  if (param instanceof B) {
    handeBType(param);
  } 
  if (param instanceof C) {
    handeCType(param);
  }
}
```

None of the if statements is hit as param is instance of 'Object' (circumstance which is a problem by itself in my application but not the subject of my question).

My understanding of Generics is that either B or C instances are required in this case as parameters for the 'doSomething' function. Plain Object should not be allowed? Or do I miss an important concept here?

Comment: `T extends A` is compile-time constraint, it does not generate any checks at runtime. `instanceof` is runtime check and is compiled as is to javascript, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964008/typescript-instanceof-not-working

Comment: Aside from the actual problem, this seems to be a design problem. A should get an abstract/dummy method "handleMe" and B and C implement their behavior. Then you can simply call instance.handleMe and you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a generic within a function declaration its usually done to reuse it someplace else in the signature of the function for example like this:

```
 doSomething<T extends A>(param: T):T {
      ....
 }
```

`doSomething` would accept a type that is a subtype of A and return the same type. This way you could reuse `doSomething` for all subtypes of A and the result would also return the same subtype.

If you want to accept two different classes that are not "related" than you could do this:

```
doSomething(param: B|C) {
      ....
 }
```

In which case the compiler would check if the parameter you're passing is either of type B or C.

As artem already mentioned: Generic definitions don't matter at runtime anymore. As we all know, the javascript engine knows no types so when you run the code in the browser or via node whatever you declared via generics is no longer known and can't help in deciding whether the if clause is true or not.

I'd say fix the problem that param is instance of 'Object' and make it an instance of B or C and you should be fine.

Not sure I understood your question correctly but I hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Thx bert, very useful