# TypeScript instanceof not working while method argument is not a plain object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a method that is called from two places where the argument type is known. In this method, the incoming argument is checked for both types yet both return false. I don't understand why this is happening. I've read the question someone else posted who had the same issue. But my problem is different because I am not constructing a plain object like he is. The question can be found here:

[TypeScript instanceof not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964008/typescript-instanceof-not-working)

Here is the method that causes the problem:

```
  changeUnitOfValueInput(filter){
    console.log((filter === undefined));
    let filterType: string;
    if (filter instanceof HTMLInputElement)
        filterType = (filter as HTMLInputElement).value;
    else if (filter instanceof AdvancedFilter){
      console.log("its in");
        filterType = (filter as AdvancedFilter).advancedFilterSubject;
    }
    else{
      console.log('im out');
       return;
    }
    switch(filterType){
      case AdvancedFilterSubject.GROWTH_TEMPERATURE:{
        this.unitLabel = (this.filterOptionsForm.controls['measureSystem'].value ==='imperial') ? '&#176;F' : '&#176;C';
        break;
      }
      case AdvancedFilterSubject.GROWTH_DAYS:{
        this.unitLabel = 'days'
        break;
      }
      //fall through
      case AdvancedFilterSubject.PLANT_HEIGHT:
      case AdvancedFilterSubject.PLANT_SPACING:
      case AdvancedFilterSubject.ROW_SPACING:
      case AdvancedFilterSubject.SOW_DEPTH:
        this.unitLabel = (this.filterOptionsForm.controls['measureSystem'].value ==='imperial') ? '&Prime;' : '&#13213;';
    }
  }
```

This method is called in this component method:

```
  populateFieldsWithSelectedFilterData(existingAdvancedFilter: AdvancedFilter){
    this.changeUnitOfValueInput(existingAdvancedFilter);
    this.filterOptionsForm.controls['filterType'].setValue(existingAdvancedFilter.advancedFilterSubject);
    this.filterOptionsForm.controls['logicalOperator'].setValue(existingAdvancedFilter.logicalOperator);
    this.filterOptionsForm.controls['advancedFilterValue'].setValue(existingAdvancedFilter.filterValue);    
  }
```

The second place where it gets called is in the frontend (html part):

```
    <p-dropdown #filterType formControlName = "filterType" placeholder="Filter type" [options]="filterTypesList" (onChange)="changeUnitOfValueInput(filterType)" >
    </p-dropdown>
```

The method keeps returning prematurely because both `instanceof` conditions return false. Can anyone tell me what is going on?

EDIT: Heres the definition of `filterTypeList` that is used in the HTML

```
  filterTypesList: SelectItem[] = [
    {label:'Minimum temperature', value: AdvancedFilterSubject.GROWTH_TEMPERATURE},
    {label:'Growth days', value: AdvancedFilterSubject.GROWTH_DAYS},
    {label:'Maximum height', value: AdvancedFilterSubject.PLANT_HEIGHT},
    {label:'Row spacing', value: AdvancedFilterSubject.ROW_SPACING},
    {label:'Plant spacing', value: AdvancedFilterSubject.PLANT_SPACING},     
    {label:'Sow depth', value: AdvancedFilterSubject.SOW_DEPTH}  
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `instanceof` to work, the prototype of the object you're using has to match the constructor function; `HTMLInputElement` or `AdvancedFilter` in this case. This won't necessarily be the case depending upon how the `AdvancedFilter` gets constructed. You may be better off creating a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isAdvancedFilter(possibleAdvancedFilter: any): possibleAdvancedFilter is AdvancedFilter {
  return possibleAdvancedFilter &&
    !!(possibleAdvancedFilter as AdvancedFilter).advancedFilterSubject;
}
```

You can of course change this function to whatever checks you need to do to ensure that the value can be used as an AdvancedFilter. Then just use `isAdvancedFilter(variable)` instead of `instanceof variable`.

Comment: can you explain this method a bit more? what does !! do? I've never seen this before. I know a single ! negates, but what does !! do exactly?

Comment: The `!!` is for a boolean cast -- it's basically checking that `.advancedFilterSubject` exists and is not falsey. You could also probably do `possibleAdvancedFilter.hasOwnProperty('advancedFilterSubject')`

Comment: also, why should i use `possibleAdvancedFilter is AdvancedFilter` ? Why not boolean?

Comment: No, it's a value cast not a type cast. `!!0 === false` for example

Comment: visual studio IDE does not indicate that something of type `any` has the property `.hasOwnProperty`. Are you sure i can use this?

Comment: Yes, that's why you need to do the `possibleAdvancedFilter &&` first; otherwise you might try to call it on null which would be an error

Comment: so what is happening here exactly, `!!(possibleAdvancedFilter as AdvancedFilter).advancedFilterSubject;`. First you are turning possibleAfvancedFilter into a AdvancedFilter, if this doesn't work because its not an instance of AdvancedFilter then the !! changes the `undefined` value into a false, if it can be cast and it is an object then !! turns it into a true value? I don't really understand and i cant find any documentation about `!!` Could you explain a bit further or give me a link that explains please? Thank you

Comment: ok, i've changed the !! part to `(possibleAdvancedFilter as AdvancedFilter).advancedFilterSubject !== undefined;` because that makes it clearer to know what is going on. Also, I found out that `possibleAdvancedFilter is AdvancedFilter` can be replaced with boolean.