# typescript instanceof return false

Tags: typescript

```
class Department {
 name: string;

 constructor(n: string) {
     this.name = n; 
 }

 describe(this: Department){
     console.log('department: ' +this.name);
 }
}

const frontend = new Department('frontend');
frontend.describe();

const frontendCopy = {name: 'Jay', describe: frontend.describe};

frontendCopy.describe();
console.log(frontendCopy instanceof Department);
console.log(frontend instanceof Department);
```

Hello, I'm a junior frontend engineer 
I wonder why

> console.log(frontendCopy instanceof Department);

print false. 
shouldn't frontendCopy.describe() be run If frontendCopy is not a instanceof Department?

but both frontend.describe() and frontendCopy.describe() works.

Comment: `frontendCopy` wasn't created using `new Department()`, so it is not an instance of `Department`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript instanceof not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45964008/typescript-instanceof-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

To make `frontendCopy` an instance of a `Department` you need to use `new Department(:string)`

```js
class Department {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name; 
    }

    describe() {
        console.log('department: ' + this.name);
    }
 
    clone(): Department {
        return new Department(this.name);
    }
}

const department = new Department('frontend');
department.describe();

const departmentCopy = department.clone();
departmentCopy.describe();

console.log(department instanceof Department);
console.log(departmentCopy instanceof Department);
```

Answer (score 2):

`department` and `departmentCopy` are created differently, and so they are differently treated.

JavaScript uses so-called "prototype OOP" (new class-oriented syntax is in fact only a syntax sugar). That means, every object has its prototype. `instanceof` operator works by leveraging this - in fact, it checks the prototype chain of its left argument to find something that satisfies the right argument.

When the value is created using `new Department`, the prototype of `department` is created based on `Department` itself. So, `department instanceof Department` checks `department.prototype`, sees that it is based on `Department` and returns `true`.

When the value is created based on the object literal, however, it is not connected with `Department` - its prototype is simply `Object` (it doesn't matter that you've copied all `Department` fields from `department` to `departmentCopy` - the prototype is set independently). So, `departmentCopy instanceof Department` sees that `Department` is not in the prototype chain and returns `false`.

As for why `departmentCopy.describe()` works - this is easy: because you created `departmentCopy` with property `describe` which is callable (i.e. function). It doesn't matter where this property originates from - class definition or manual setting.

Answer (score 0):

Really sorry for you waiting my response. 
I found some documentation and it explained me a lot about class and inheritance.

In the section of 'Understanding private' which I linked below, even Animal and Employee have same structure, It's perfectly different.

It might seems weird why I mentioned example about class and inheritance topic, but I think we can get some hint over here.

[https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-private][1]

By the way, Thanks for your all answers and comments. 
There might be some misunderstanding in my words, you can leave on your own freely.

Thanks once again!