# Why is instanceof not working as expected in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype

So I have these classes that I use to handle errors in different scenerios like so:

```
export class APIError extends Error {
    public readonly statusCode: number;
    public readonly message: string;

    constructor(statusCode?: number, message?: string) {
        super(message);
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, APIError.prototype);

        if (typeof statusCode === 'string') {
            message = statusCode;
            statusCode = null;
        }

        this.statusCode = statusCode || 500;
        this.message = message || 'Internal Server Error';
    }

    public toJSON(): JsonData {
        return {
            statusCode: this.statusCode,
            message: this.message,
        };
    }
}

export class NotFound extends APIError {
    constructor(message?: string) {
        super(404, 'Not Found');
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, NotFound.prototype);
    }
}

export class StreamNotFound extends NotFound {
    constructor() {
        super('Stream Not Found');
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, StreamNotFound.prototype);
    }
}
```

And then I have this update abstract method:

```
public update(id: string, updateThing: T): T {
        if (!updateThing) return;

        const thing: T = this.get(id);
        if (!thing) {
            throw new NotFound(`${this.displayName} could not be found.`);
        }
      ....
```

In my controller, I'm trying to catch the error and then get it's instance like so:

```
} catch (e) {
            const statusCode = (e instanceof StreamNotFound) ? 404 : null;
            throw HttpController.handleError(e, statusCode);
        }
```

But statusCode will always return null, even though streamNotFound extends NotFound, and Notfound is being used by the Update abstract method.

As you can see, I'm adding the `Object.setPrototypeOf(this, StreamNotFound.prototype);` on each of the methods, so I'm wondering why it is not working as expected?

Comment: You're thinking of inheritance in a reverse way: an instance of StreamNotFound is also an instance of NotFound, but an instance of a NotFound is not an instance of StreamNotFound. By the way: why on earth do you need those `.setPrototypeOf()`'s? `class`es set up their prototypes automatically.

Comment: If you're viewing this question, you probably would be more interested in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45964008/2065702)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A subclass will always be an `instanceof` itself and any of its parent classes. However, the reverse is not true: a parent class is not an `instanceof` any of its subclasses.

In this example, `StreamNotFound instanceof NotFound === true`. However, a parent class is explicitly **not** `instanceof` any of its subclasses. Here, `NotFound instanceof StreamNotFound === false`.

In your controller, you're `throw`ing an instance of `NotFound`, which will never be an `instanceof StreamNotFound`, as it's further up in the prototype chain than its subclasses.

---

In the simplified example below, `Bar` extends `Foo` as a subclass, thus:

- `Foo instanceof Foo === true`
- `Bar instanceof Foo === true`
- `Bar instanceof Bar === true`
- `Foo instanceof Bar === false`

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
  
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

const obj1 = new Foo();
const obj2 = new Bar();

console.log("Bar instanceof Bar: " + (obj2 instanceof Bar));
console.log("Bar instanceof Foo: " + (obj2 instanceof Foo));
console.log("Foo instanceof Bar: " + (obj1 instanceof Bar));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a root class of `NodeCore` with two classes that extended that class: `Leaf` and `Choice`. I was attempting to use a type that allowed either subclass:

```
type Node = Leaf | Choice;
```

Then I was attempting to check the `instanceof` that type:

```
if (node instanceof Node) { ... }
```

This doesn't work. But checking `instanceof` of the *original class* does work:

```
if (node instanceof NodeCore) { ... }
```